# Latex equations are not displaying in R Notebook preview/output properly

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, mathjax, rnotebook

Take for example

```
$ \theta_{posterior} \leq  -1.645*\sigma_{posterior}$ and $ \theta_{posterior}  \geq  1.645*\sigma_{posterior}
$
```

It displays perfectly fine in the R Studio Viewer.

[latex equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIH1p.png)

However, if I preview the file it merely displays text

> {posterior} 1.645{posterior}

I thought R Studio had mathjax for rendering latex equations? Is there something else I need to install? All I can find online is in regards to installing MikTex for rendering pdfs.

Comment: I have this issue; am on High Sierra with `RStudio 1.1.419`